# How to print vector<int> to terminal in c++

Tags: c++, vector, cout

I am trying to print a vector of integers to the terminal using "cout", but I get an error message during compiling:

> no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream' and 'std::vector')
>        cout << "Disparity at points: " << disparityVector << endl;

The snippet of code looks like this:

```
vector<int> disparityVector;

for ( int i=0; i<drawPixels.size(); i++)    // Get disparity at each point of the drawn line
  disparityVector.push_back((int)disparityMapOutput.at<int16_t>(pos[i].y, pos[i].x));

cout << "Disparity at points: " << disparityVector << endl;
```

There is no error with assigning the values to the vector, only the "cout" part of the code is making errors

Comment: You CANT just `cout <<` a vector,  you need to iterate on it and cout each value separately.

Comment: Or you could write your own `std::basic_ostream::operator << (const std::vector&)` as the error suggests

Comment: `for(auto& value : disparityVector) cout << value << " ";`

Comment: I have already used this method to output another vector further up in my code, but this is of type "vector<Point>"

Comment: @eirikaso then you probably have a non-templated version, rather than the template in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need something like below, if you want to do it the way you've coded it.

```
template<class T>
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, std::vector<T> const& v) {
  for (auto const& i : v)
    o << i << " ";
  return o;
}
```

Comment: You could do with a separator

Answer (score 5):

For example, using [`ostream_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostream_iterator/).

Sample from that page:

```
// ostream_iterator example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::ostream_iterator
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy

int main () {
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) myvector.push_back(i*10);

  std::ostream_iterator<int> out_it (std::cout,", ");
  std::copy ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), out_it );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vector<int>& v)
{
    std::ostream_iterator<int> _oit(cout, " ");
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), _oit);
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that `vector<T>` has no `operator<<` implementation.
You need to iterate over your vector and print each element:

```
for(int i = 0; i < disparityVector.size; i++) {
    cout << disparityVector[i];
}
cout << endl;
```